# I want to reset the progress/angular-kendo-editor control in my form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to reset the value of kendo-editor control.

I have tried the below items:

```
this.requestForm.controls.note.reset();
      
this.requestForm.controls.note.setValue('');
      
this.requestForm.reset();

this.requestForm.reset({ note: '' });

this.requestForm.patchValue({ note: '' });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the options you tested and it is working well. But you might wanna try the code below. I also added a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmxne1?file=app/app.component.ts).

Try this:

```
this.requestForm.get('note').setValue('');
```

Comment: Thanks for your stack blitz link. It helped me to identify the issue.
I was disabling the field before re-setting the value. That was the issue.

 (this.requestForm.controls.note.disable();)